# Without using packages, how to calculate number of years,months,days between two dates in python

Tags: python-3.x

We can calculate number of years,months,days between two dates using dateutil pakage.In my code i have used indexing to get years,  months and days.but dateutil package-'relativedelta' object does not support indexing. request for help on calculating number of years,months,days between two dates without using package.

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time


class Employee:
        raise_amt = 1.05

        def __init__(self, first, last, pay, birthdate='07-03-1991', joindate='31-12-2013'):
            self.first = first
            self.last = last
            self.pay = int(pay)
            self.birthdate = birthdate #instance variable
            self.joindate = joindate
            self.first = first + "." + last + "@company.com"

        def exeperience(self): #calculating experience
            self.joindate = datetime.strptime(self.joindate, '%d-%m-%Y')
            today = date.today()
            experience = ((today.year-self.joindate.year),(today.month-self.joindate.month),(today.day - self.joindate.day))

            return experience

        @classmethod
        def from_string(cls, emp_str):
            first, last, pay = emp_str.split('-')
            return cls(first, last, pay)


emp_str_1 = 'Nanda-Reddy-45412'

emp_1 = Employee.from_string(emp_str_1)

sync=emp_1.exeperience()
print('Employee experience is{} years {} months {}days:'.format(sync[0],sync[1],sync[2]))
```

> Output: Employee experience is3 years -2 months -9days: But the exact
>   output should be 2 years 10 months 22 days.Help me on getting this
>   output.

Comment: that's more an astronomy related question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't express a date delta in the relative form "YYYY years, MM months and DD days" precisely, since the days of each month are different and there are leap years, your result will be ambiguous. But if you just need some description, here's the code:

```
def exeperience(self): #calculating experience
    self.joindate = datetime.strptime(self.joindate, '%d-%m-%Y')
    today = date.today()
    days = (today - self.joindate).days
    years, days = days // 365, days % 365
    months, days = days // 30, days % 30
    return (years, months, days)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have defined a function daysBetweenDates(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2) that will give the desired result. I've also created smaller sub functions that are used in this main function. Leap year definition used is - years divisible by 4 and by 400 if they are century years. Thanks.

```
def daysinyear (year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        days = 366
        if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 !=0:
            days = 365
            return days
        return days
    days = 365
    return days

def daysbwwholeyears(year1,year2):
    i=year1
    days=0
    while i<=year2:
        days = daysinyear(i) + days
        i=i+1
    return days


def daystodate (month,day,year):
    days = summonth (month - 1,year) + day
    return days

def summonth (month,year):#is mahine ke end tak kitne din ho chuke
    if year % 4 == 0:
        daysinmonth = [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
        days = 0
        i=0
        while i< month:
            days = days + daysinmonth[i]
            i=i+1
        return days

    daysinmonth = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    days = 0
    i=0
    while i< month:
        days = days + daysinmonth[i]
        i=i+1
    return days

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    if year2 - year1 ==0:
        days = daystodate(month2,day2,year2) - daystodate(month1,day1,year1)
        return days

    if year2 - year1 ==1:
        days = daysinyear(year1) - daystodate(month1,day1,year1) +     daystodate(month2,day2,year2)
        return days


    days = daysbwwholeyears(year1+1,year2-1) + daysinyear(year1) -  daystodate(month1,day1,year1) + daystodate(month2,day2,year2)
    return days
```